# Problems with ruby version when bundle install

Tags: ruby

If I give Bundle install I get

```
Gem::InstallError: factory_girl requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.
```

But if I do ruby -v I get

```
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]
```

So the problem should be in rails or in bundle that uses the previous version of it, how can I fix it?

Comment: Try running `bundle exec ruby -v` to see if Bundler runs the same version of Ruby as you think. Could be an environment issue.

Comment: ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]

Comment: I encountered something similar. Try running bundle check and seeing that that turns up anything. You may need to delete your Gemfile.lock and then run bundle check again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved reinstalling Ruby from source code and compiling!

Answer (score 0):

You are using rbenv?

The ~/.bash_profile file needs to be modified:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```